# Water (pool, puddle) segmentation algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

Is there a generic computer vision technique that can be used to detect water (puddles, pools...) in a video? The video should be acquired from a camera attached to a drone, and this drone should not be too far above the water (10 to 30 meters above).

I'm specifying that the water should be in a pool or puddle, because the water should be standing, not moving in relation to its surroundings.

Comment: Sounds like a simple color based method might be worth looking at, I suggest trying k-means clustering or Felzenswalb and Huttenlochers graph-based image segmentation method. To avoid individual pixel within the pool to be mislabeled due to reflections you might want to compute superpixels first (e.g. using SLIC, SEEDS or something similar), and the hierarchically cluster/segment the superpixels.

Comment: @DavidStutz Thanks. I will try something out. I've also found a paper that I'm trying to replicate, seems promising. You may want to check it. It's named "Daytime Water Detection Based on Color Variation", from Arturo Rankin and Larry Matthies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was quite an interesting task to verify  multi-color segmentation can handle pools. Long story short, it definitely can, but pools are quite tricky anyway.

[image]

First of all, it will not be enough to have "water detection and color variation" paper. You'll also need "pools design and color variation" handbook.

[image]

Moreover, specific landscape, architecture, point of view, etc provide more colors to be used.
[image]
It might be easier to train a neural net to recognize some specific patterns, but blue color variations as a poor man solution might also do the trick.

Here is a [complete 4K example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAf-0mXUmUM)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing. The task I initially had is now long gone. We didn't figure out a reliable way to detect water back then. However, nowadays if I had to try again I would use some neural network as you suggested. Would be very easy to get samples and I had some experience with CNNs afterwards.

Comment: It was hard to leave such an interesting question without an answer :) Thank you.